# cannot ouput the project info to the xml files by doxygen

Tags: xml, output, doxygen

I used doxygen generate output files including Html and XML files, I can see the project informations such as project name and project number in the Html files but cannot see any in the XML files.
and I tried to put the project number in automatically by setting "PROJECT_NUMBER=$(PROJECT_NUMBER) and running "PROJECT_NUMBER=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) doxygen" in the command line, the real project number appeared in the html files but there is only "$(PROJECT_NUMBER)" in the xml file.

Has anybody encountered a similar issue? How did you solve it?

Comment: I had a quick look at the code (btw which version of doxygen are you using?) and I don't see a reference to `PROJECT_NUMBER` in the xml output generator. Same accounts for `PROJECT_BRIEF` and `PROJECT_LOGO`. I think worth creating an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

Comment: Actually there is already and proposed pull request for this: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/153

Comment: Thank you. Doxygen version is 1.8.17. 
So what can I do now? Update the doxygen? I think this is the latest version.

Comment: 1.8.17 is the latest version. At the moment there is, unfortunately, no solution (other than editing manually your xml files and add the information), we have to wait till the proposed pull request is integrated or another solution has been created.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you again.